# Download a section of a webpage as an image with same design for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, jquery, jspdf, dom-to-image

I am using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library so whenever a user click on a button I want to download that section as an image. It is working fine on desktop. But, in mobile the image is downloading like a responsive mobile design. On mobile view it should download the image like it shows in the desktop view.
I tried changing the viewport to 1500px once the user click the button then download the image as a desktop version and once done revert back to mobile responsive design but I dont want it like that.

Comment: This might help you out [Set Height Width in dom to image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#height-width)

Comment: @groovy_guy I tried that but it is just increasing the width of the html elements. I want it to download as a desktop view.